# Magento 'Add To Cart' text change and redirect URL

Tags: magento, url, redirect, cart

I need this to be available just for some products*

Change the 'add to cart' button text to 'Find Out More'.

Also, once they click on the 'Find Out More' button to be redirected to a different URL on the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill this requirement, you can create a product attribute (yes/no type),and get its value in addtocart.phtml.

According to its value, you can put your code for changing label and redirect url.

I hope this is the simplest solution. Please feel free if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create attribute for all same product. as an example "find out more" =  "yes/no".

you need to code in app/design/frontend/[your-package]/[Your-Theme']/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
if($yourattribute == "yes"){
<a id="find_out_more" class="button btn-cart" href="your-link" >Find Out More</a>
}else{
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
}
```

place above code in addtocart.phtml

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Went through all the steps and got this back                     See screen grab in link:    http://postimg.org/image/8ao8w1mth/

Comment: please add like this <a href="your-link" class="button btn-cart" ><span><span><?php echo "Find Out More" ?></span></span></a>   http://prntscr.com/7wypoj

Comment: …. I have one attribute ‘find out more’ with yes or no and then an attribute for getting the link ‘get_link’ if I choose yes for the first one.
My code I guess should be the if- else type. If the ‘find out more’ attribute is YES link my add to cart button with the URL found under the get_link attribute.

Comment: if (condition) {
    show this button and link it to the ‘get_link’
} else {
    use normal  add to cart button
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: <?php if($_product->getData('find_out_more')==1){?>

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
} else {

Comment: <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
 <?php } ?>                They break a bit the design but they seem to work, although onclick instead of linking to a link, I need it to open the link found under ‘get_link’ attribute. (this is if the first button)

Comment: Did you mean you have one another attribute link for same product?

Comment: Hi, yes... Being able to change between 'add to cart' and 'find out more' buttons from the product attribute (with yes/no).  If i choose yes, show 'find out more' if no leave normal 'add to cart' button.  And the 'find out more' button to take the url from another attribute.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this by the way :).

Answer (score 0):

This is path for changing the "Add to cart" button text on product page:

```
/app/design/frontend/Your-theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```